# Designing an extensible pipeline with Python

Tags: python, pipeline

**Context:** I'm currently using Python to a code a data-reduction pipeline for a large astronomical imaging system. The main pipeline class passes experimental data through a number of discrete processing 'stages'.

The stages are written in separate .py files which constitute a package. A list of available stages is generated at runtime so the user can choose which stages to run the data through. 
The aim of this approach is to allow the user to create additional stages in the future.

**Issue:** All of the pipeline configuration parameters and data structures are (currently) located within the main pipeline class. Is there a simple way to access these from within the stages which are imported at runtime?

My current best attempt seems 'wrong' and somewhat primitive, as it uses circular imports and class variables. Is there perhaps a way for a pipeline instance to pass a reference to itself as an argument to each of the stages it calls?

This is my first time coding a large python project and my lack of design knowledge is really showing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can avoid circular imports by implementing a `stage` baseclass and derive from that. The main class then needs only to import the baseclass. The derived stages would import the baseclass and (maybe) the main class.

Comment: Take a look at this before you go any further: http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=pipeline&submit=search

Comment: There is a pipeline mechanism for Plone to manage data import/export that might be interesting thing to look at for design ideas (and possible code). You can find it on pypi: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.transmogrifier

Comment: Have you looked at [MDP](http://mdp-toolkit.sourceforge.net/)? That's a pipeline-structured number crunching toolkit.

Comment: That looks really interesting, thanks!

Comment: That one looks effective..
http://pypipegraph.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#second-summary

Comment: Of the packages listed at http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=pipeline&submit=search, my personal favorite is [ruffus](http://code.google.com/p/ruffus/).

Comment: Thanks guys. I now have more information than my small brain can process :p

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've built a similar system; it's called [`collective.transmogrifier`](https://github.com/mjpieters/collective.transmogrifier). One of these days I'll make it more generic (it is currently tied to the CMF, one of the underpinnings of Plone).

#### Decoupling

What you need, is a way to decouple the component registration for your pipeline. In Transmogrifier, I use the [Zope Component Architucture](http://wiki.zope.org/zope3/ComponentArchitecture) (embodied in the [`zope.component`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.component) package). The ZCA lets me register components that implement a given interface and later look up those components as either a sequence or by name. There are other ways of doing this too, for example, python eggs have the concept of [entry points](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#dynamic-discovery-of-services-and-plugins).

The point is more that each component in the pipeline is referable by a text-only name, de-referenced at construction time. 3rd-party components can be slotted in for re-use by registering their own components independently from your pipeline package.

#### Configuration

Transmogrifier pipelines are configured using a textual format based on the [python `ConfigParser` module](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html), where different components of the pipeline are named, configured, and slotted together. When constructing the pipeline, each section thus is given a configuration object. Sections don't have to look up configuration centrally, the are configured on instantiation.

#### Central state

I also pass in a central 'transmogrifier' instance, which represents the pipeline. If any component needs to share per-pipeline state (such as caching a database connection for re-use between components), they can do so on that central instance. So in my case, each section does have a reference to the central pipeline.

#### Individual components and behaviour

Transmogrifier pipeline components are generators, that consume elements from a preceding component in the pipeline, then yield the results of their own processing. Components generally thus have a reference to the previous stage, but have no knowledge of what consumes their output. I say 'generally' because in Transmogrifier some pipeline elements can produce elements from an external source instead of using a previous element.

If you do need to alter the behaviour of a pipeline component based on individual items to be processed, mark those items themselves with extra information for each component to discover. In Transmogrifier, items are dictionaries, and you can add extra keys to a dictionary that use the name of a component so each component can look for this extra info and alter behaviour as needed.

#### Summary

- Decouple your pipeline components by using an indirect lookup of elements based on a configuration.
- When you instantiate your components, configure them at the same time and give them what they need to do their job. That could include a central object to keep track of pipeline-specific state.
- When running your pipeline, only pass through items to process, and let each component base it's behaviour on that individual item only.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. There's a lot of info there! :)

Comment: I think I'll need to draw up some diagrams to get my head around your system. It sounds very powerful and would probably get used a LOT if it was totally generic. I know several people trying to code pipelines from scratch who would love this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

[Ruffus](http://www.ruffus.org.uk/) is a python library "designed to allow scientific and other analyses to be automated with the minimum of fuss and the least effort".

**Positive**: It allows incremental processing of data and you can define very complicated sequences. Additionally, tasks are automatically parallelized. It allows you to switch on/off functions and their order is defined automatically from the patterns you specify.

**Negative**: it is sometimes too pythonic for my taste, it only switches and orders functions and not, for example, classes. But then of course you can have the code to initialize the classes within each function.

For the purpose you want, you use the **@active_if** identifier above a function, to enable it or disable it over the pipeline. You can retrieve whether it is going to be activated from an external configuration file, which you read with a **ConfigParser**.

In order to load the ConfigParser values, you have to write another python module, which initializes the  ConfigParser instance. This module has to be imported on the first lines of the pipeline module.

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1. Have configuration somewhere else: have a config module, and use something like the django config system to make that available.
2. Instead of having the stages import the pipeline class, pass them a pipeline instance on instantiation.

Comment: I like your second suggestion. As far as config is concerned, I'm using the Python ConfigParser system to load settings from a config file into a nested dictionary structure at the moment. Running Django isn't an option in my particular circumstances.

Comment: @JimR The point is not that you should use django, but that you could use something like that django component. You might well find something separate, or if you really like the django approach, you could separate out the config system (django is pretty modular, although not packaged as separate modules).

Answer (score 2):

A colleague of mine has worked on a similar pipeline for astrophysical synthetic emission maps from simulation data (svn checkout https://svn.gforge.hlrs.de/svn//opensesame).

The way he does this is:

The config lives in a separate object (actually a dictionary as in your case).

The stages are either:

- receive the config object at instantiation as a constructor argument
- get the config through assignment later on (e.g. stage.config = config_object)
- receive the config object as an argument when executed (e.g. stage.exec(config_object, other_params))

Comment: Thanks very much Steffen. This seems like a simple solution to my issue.